# How to setup DNS Server on Local network

Tags: 11.10, server, dns, bind

Im having a Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop system,how can I configure the `BIND` server to resolve as the following:

> I should be able to use Google's Public DNS for the internet
>
> www.rootserver.com should resolve to my computer
>
> www.wifi.device should resolve to 192.168.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) instead, is pretty far more easy to configure than bind: you just need to install it, and it will use DNS defined in /etc/resolv.conf as upstream server, and in /etc/hosts you can define the 2 records you need.

Remember to reload it on every change.