# Setup DNS server for local network (with DHCP) for use with apache

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, dhcp

I've set up an ubuntu-server to host a website. But at first i want to configure it to work in my local network.

Actually it serves as DHCP server for the whole network with static ip 192.168.170.250 (and configured, but not accessable hostname "ubuntu-server") and now i want to access this server (and all the apache virtual-hosts) via hostnames.

I already tried to install and configure a DNS server on this machine but without success... (Those tutorials didn't work for me: [Tutorial 1](http://lani78.wordpress.com/2012/07/22/setting-up-a-dns-for-the-local-network-on-the-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-server/) and [Tutorial 2](http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/11/07/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-in-ubuntu/))

Also read other questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70909/how-to-setup-dns-server-on-local-network) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162265/how-to-setup-dhcp-server-and-dynamic-dns-with-bind) but the first one is a complete different question and the other is confusing me because i don't understand the impact of the differences to the first mentioned tutorials... (And I would really prefer to understand what i'm doing and configurating...)

I just want to write something like "ubuntu-server.home.lan" on any PC in my network to access my ubuntu-server, or "website1.home.lan" to access a virtual host of apache running on my ubuntu-server.
And maybe later register this server to an official domain to make it accessible from web...

I would be glad for every hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where the difference is between the first tutorials and the one i tried now but now it works.

This tutorial did help me:
[Worked](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236093)

Comment: Please add the answer that has been given in the link that you provided, to your answer rather than just posting the link itself.