# How to setup a local web server to connect from another machine

Tags: networking, server, webserver

I would like to setup a local network with one Ubuntu server and multiple clients(Ubuntu desktop). I need to install web server (lamp) in server and all Client machines needs to access the web server and share files installed in main Ubuntu server.
I know how to install Lamp in Ubuntu but I don't know about dns configurations to access the local web server from other machines. Also I am very new to Linux So any step by step tutorial would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.
**Edit:** The answers suggested here are kind of old around ubuntu 6. I am looking for an answer for Ubuntu 15.04
I followed the below tutorial which is explained in a detailed manner. I got the dns to work but still have some questions, so I am opening a new topic for that.
http://lani78.com/2012/07/22/setting-up-a-dns-for-the-local-network-on-the-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-server/ 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/633416/how-to-configure-lamp-for-ubuntu-server-so-to-load-example-local-domain-to-my-we

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup DNS server for local network (with DHCP) for use with apache](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217303/setup-dns-server-for-local-network-with-dhcp-for-use-with-apache)

Comment: You can see http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/1/. This link shows how to use nginx as your webserver. I have followed and was able to install a working server in a VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great working tutorial for ubuntu 12.04 from an expert and got it worked.
http://lani78.com/2012/07/22/setting-up-a-dns-for-the-local-network-on-the-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-server/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what are you looking for...

[Setup DNS server for local network (with DHCP) for use with apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217303/setup-dns-server-for-local-network-with-dhcp-for-use-with-apache)

Regards